# Java XML Schema library which can suggest descendents of xsd element

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have XML Schema (which import other schemas). I want to find library which can show all children that every element in this schema has. I know that e.g. eclipse has this kind of functionality (it suggests elements that I can use under some node), but I don't know which library is it.

In my application user can add schemas so generating classes with JAXB or XML Beans won't work.

The best would be open-source library that can be used for commercial purpose (e.g. licence LGPL).

Answer (score 0):

Service Data Objects ([JSR-235](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=235)) could be used for this scenario:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-sdo.html

Here is license information on [EclipseLink SDO](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/sdo.php) (I'm the tech lead):

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/General#How_is_EclipseLink_Licensed.3F

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Library that you showed me do what I want to do. However it throws NullPointerException at schema "crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/osoba/2008/05/09/osoba.xsd"; (however it works great with crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/adres/2008/05/09/adres.xsd). I need my application to work with this schema and I am sure it is correct. I tried versions 2.2, 2.1.2 and 2.0.2 and all have the same error. Line that cause exception is: `XSDHelper.INSTANCE.define(new URL("http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/osoba/2008/05/09/osoba.xsd").openStream(), null);`

Answer (score 0):

[XSOM](http://xsom.java.net/) might fit the bill.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking at the XSOM. It is very interesting library, but it didn't give exactly what I want (or maybe I am missing something). What I want to have is a method that will give me for every tag in XML list of possible childes that this element might have (based on schema). I didn't find it in XSOM, but definitely this library can help me write this kind of functionality.